# mkRunning multiple Gradle tasks in a single Jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am working with Jenkins and need to take two tasks (currently running in their own job) and have them run in a single job, one after the other.  This should be a very simple thing to do where you simply specify the tasks separated by a space (see attachment).  However, it runs the first task and never the second task.

I also tried adding separate Gradle tasks in the same job, yet I get the same result: Gradle task #1 runs, but it never executes the second task.   (see attachment).

This should be a very straightforward configuration, but clearly I am missing something here to get this working.

[Gradle tasks separated by a space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PSwk.jpg)

[Separate Gradle tasks in the same job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYXb2.jpg)

Details:

The second task, when run in its own job, runs without issue. The test automation that this is running is visible in the environment it runs against, and looking over the console output.

Essentially the first task runs as it normally does and the job completes. When I switch the task order and see if it runs I see the following in the logs:

```
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for /ajaxExecutors by username. Returning 403. </content></entry><entry><title>Found invalid crumb {0}.
```

`DefaultTestListener` does not have a no-args constructor when I switch the order of the jobs.

It looks like the issue may be in the code, and not the way Jenkins itself is executing the Gradle tasks.

Comment: If the second task never runs in either case it is probably a no-op. Does it work using the same Gradle wrapper locally? How do you know it is running? Have you look at the Jenkins logs?

Comment: BTW all these research details should be in the question text via an [edit].

Comment: Oh...sorry.  My first post on StackO.  I fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

It turned out to be an issue with TestNG where the class,

`class DefaultTestListener implements ITestListener` ,was not a public class.  By making the class public, it resolved the issue.

`public class DefaultTestListener implements ITestListener`